# POST doesn't complete if I refresh page

Tags: jquery, ajax, post

I have a form which uses $.ajax on submit to call a bash script that writes data to a text file.

In Firefox, if i immediately refresh the page or navigate to a different page, the POST aborts, and the text file does not update:

> [15:07:12.781] POST http://server/writegit.cgi [undefined 891ms]

If I wait a second or two before refreshing, the POST completes and everything is fine:

> [15:03:04.995] POST http://server/writegit.cgi [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 2022ms]

However, this problem does not happen in Chrome-- once the form submits, the POST will complete even if I refresh the page immediately.

Is there any way I can make Firefox behave like Chrome?

Comment: Curious why anyone would want that.

Comment: change the page immediately after the action is done and before the confirmation came back

Comment: i don't really want or need the ajax response, i just want users to be assured that once the click 'save', then their data is saved. I'm using $.ajax because my data isn't -actually- in a form, it's a just attached to a .click and I dont want the page to refresh. There's probably a better way-- do you know what it is?

Comment: 1. follow the Diodeus advice 2. add some throbber so user sees that the process hasn't finished yet

Comment: yes, considered the throbber but that's a pretty lame solution, considering Chrome handles it elegantly

Comment: the application should be informative enough regardless any specific browser features

Comment: @zerkms yes, i agree, and if this is the only solution, i will do it-- but if there's a way to make Firefox behave like Chrome, then there is no need

Comment: doubtfully you can control that behaviour

Comment: fixed it using Diodeus' suggestion (sync request)

Comment: yes, and in case of bad connection or issues on your side you get the client's tab frozen :-S

Comment: it's on an intranet without about a dozen users-- not really worried about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ajax calls are asynchronous - meaning they fire off and sometime in the future a response will come. The code does not wait for the response. If you navigate away from the page before this happens, you pull the rug out from under the request.

Either make the call synchronous, or add some "onbeforeunload" event handler to check if your ajax call has completed before allowing the user to navigate away from the page.

or: just don't refresh the page!

Comment: added async: 'false' to the $.ajax request, but the problem persists... any ideas?

Comment: ah, works now-- I had to ditch the quotes. Browser does lock up for a second in Firefox (not Chrome), but not a big deal. Thanks!

Comment: window.onbeforeunload = function() { return confirm("You havent's saved data yet!") }